# Continuous functions satisfying $2f(x) = f(2x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Can I just say that continuous solutions to the equation 
$$
f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)
$$
(for all $x$,$y$) are of the form $f(x) = kx$ so our solution set is of the form $kx$ as well? Then plugging in $kx$ gives $k=0,2$ but I'm not sure if this is a valid way to do it..

Comment: This should be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address the equation in the title, since it leads to an important subtlety people often overlook.

Let $g(x):=x^{-1}f(x)$ so $g(2x)=g(x)$. Let $h(x):=g(e^x)$ so $h(x+\ln 2)=h(x)$. Any periodic function, its argument scaled so the period is $\ln 2$, gives us a solution $f$. Continuity narrows the choices of $h$ somewhat, but it needn't be constant. A less trivial solution, for example, is $$f(x)=x\cos\frac{2\pi \ln x}{\ln 2}.$$One may object this breaks for $x\le 0$, but $f(2x)=2f(x)$ requires only that $f(0)=0$, and if we define $f(x)$ for positive and negative $x$ separately there is no issue. For example, we could take $f$ to be odd and simply replace $\ln x$ in the above with $\lvert\ln x\rvert$.

Comment: So then I can't take it to be kx?

Comment: @Saad If the only thing you know is $2f(x)=f(2x)$, no. If you know $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for continuous $f$ one can prove $f(x)=xf(1)$. (Hint: prove for integers, then rationals, then see what continuity implies on $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Well, you can set $f(x)=kx$, but the set of solutions is much bigger, as @J.G. has proved.

Comment: @J.G. Can we show that any continuous solution is of the form $x * g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is continuous and 2-periodic?

Comment: @Saad We need some care at $x=0$, and technically $g$ is said to be log-periodic.

Comment: @J.G. What do you mean?

Comment: @Saad Log-periodic functions are periodic functions of a logarithm.

Comment: @J.G. No, about the $x=0$ part

Comment: @Saad You don't necessarily know that $g$ is continuous at $0$ just because $f$ is.